# Toolbar aligned to the right in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

My toolbar1 is aligned to the right, but I do not want it. How can I remove this alignment?

My JS:

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytextarea',
        theme: 'modern',
        skin: 'lightgray',
        menubar: false,
        branding: false,
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
            "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor colorpicker textpattern",
            "pagebreak"
        ],

        setup: function (editor) {

        },

        toolbar1: "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
        toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor | insertdatetime preview | forecolor backcolor",
        toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks | pagebreak",
        init_instance_callback: "renderEditor",
        height: "300"
});
```

Here is how it display:
[image]

Does anybody know why the toolbar1 is aligned to the right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put below styles to list.css file

```
.mce-content-body ol[align="center"],
.mce-content-body ol li[align="center"],
.mce-content-body ul[align="center"],
.mce-content-body ul li[align="center"] {
    text-align: center;
}
.mce-content-body ol[align="left"],
.mce-content-body ol li[align="left"],
.mce-content-body ul[align="left"],
.mce-content-body ul li[align="left"] {
    text-align: left;
}
.mce-content-body ol[align="right"],
.mce-content-body ol li[align="right"],
.mce-content-body ul[align="right"],
.mce-content-body ul li[align="right"] {
    text-align: right;
}
```

And then use it on tinymce.init() function

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#tinymce-textarea',
    content_css: ['list.css']
});
```